# MongoDB sort with score for text seach along with other criteria spring data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have mongo document for ecommerce products. I want to sort based on search score. I have other parameters also in find clause. My query is:

```
db.getCollection('product').find({category_id:42, $text: 
{$search:'red'}},{'score': {'$meta': 'textScore'}}).sort({'score': {'$meta': 'textScore'}}).limit(50)
```

How to perform same in spring data?

I have used query and andcriteria but not able to sort based on score:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("category_id").is(42));
 query.addCriteria(TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().
 matching("red"));

mongoTemplate.find(query, A.class, "product");
```

But here no option to sort using score. How to sort based on score?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.textsearch) and use a `TextQuery` to apply sorting by score.

```
TextQuery query = new TextQuery(TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matching("red"));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("category_id").is(42));
query.sortByScore();
```

I created [DATAMONGO-2407](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2407) to improve the docs by making the sort option more visible.